# How to loop and update SQL table summing any existing values

Tags: c#, sql, c#-4.0, ado.net

Please i need your help on this module part of my program. i have 2 tables, **TableA** which has **"code,description,value"** and **TableB** which has **"code, values"** example below :

TableA

```
code    description value
-----------------------------               
CD1     BOOKS      
CD2     BREADS     
CD3     PHONES  
CD4     FISH
```

TableB

```
code    value1  value2  value3  value4
--------------------------------------
cd1    12     21     10         21
cd2     9     10     10         11
cd3    19     11     29         13
cd4    10     12     22         12
```

the idea is to update **TableA** with the Values of **TableB** where **TableA.code=TableB.code** but if their are values in **TableA** then Update content of **TableA**  Value field by adding the new values to the old value field where **TableB.code = TableA.code**. i have written the following code but it's only updating one row, below is my code :

```
DataTable dt = GetDatafromDatabase(); //===== returns a DataTable

string SQLT = "SELECT * FROM tbl_TempReport";

if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)   {cn.Open();   }
SqlCommand cmdT = new SqlCommand(SQLT, cn);
while (rt.Read())
{
// For each row, print the values of each column.
foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
{
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
colname = column.ColumnName.ToString();
string m_Code = rt["code"].ToString();
if (m_Code == colname) {
if (m_Code == colname && mValue > 0) { mValue +=         Convert.ToInt32(row[column].ToString()); } else { mValue = Convert.ToInt32(row[column].ToString()); }
//============ insert into tbl_TempReport to match the appropriate column 

string SQLP = "UPDATE tbl_TempReport SET VALUEP = @VALUEP WHERE code =     @code";
SqlCommand cmdp = new SqlCommand(SQLP, cn);
cmdp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VALUEP", SqlDbType.Int).Value = mValue;
cmdp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =     rt["code"].ToString();
cmdp.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
}
}
}
```

i need your help to achieve this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, this can be done in a single update statement, without any loops:

```
UPDATE a 
SET value = b.value1 + b.value2 + b.value3 + b.value4 + COALESCE(value, 0)
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b ON(a.code = b.code)
```

Comment: Zohar Peled, thank you for the assistance. The issue is that i have two tables TableA that has three(3) columns "code, description,valuep" and TableB that has two(2) column "Code, Values" all these tables have 2000 records. The idea is search TableB  where code match code of TableA Update the Valuep of TableA with Values of TableB, but if TableA already have data in Valuep column  then sum it to the current data. repeat it for all the 2000 records. with what i have done it only affecting just two(2) records. help me please